# Stock touch sensitive Silverlight 4/Windows 7 Mobile Image display control

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, touch, gesture

i've seen this question: [SO - W7M gesture events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936185/silverlight-windows-phone-7-gesture-events) but my requirements slightly different. Has anyone encountered a gesture aware image viewer control that supports pinch/squeeze/scroll? The SL4 toolkit add-ons are a partial win but do not take it far enough. If neccessary I can code all from scratch but would prefer not to duplicate effort at this point.

Thx++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pretty great implementation of pinch zoom that I encountered when I asked a similar question.

[Constraints on Image Width/Height on WP7 GestureListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507416/constraints-on-image-width-height-on-wp7-gesturelistener)